# Why I can't have a click listener on a checkbox, when I have a listener on the <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a really newbie question here, but I can't understand what is going on.

I have this table:

```
<table class="activeTrackersTable" id="allTrackersTable" data-page-navigation=".pagination">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th class="reactivateTH">Reactivate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ObjArray">
        <tr data-bind="click: loadT">
            <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: tName"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: pName"></span>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: creator"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="reactivateTD">
                <input type="checkbox" name="reactivate" data-bind="event:{change: reactivate}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div class="pagination"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Now as you see I have placed a listener on the `tr` and it works just perfectly, But when I click on the `checkbox` I'm getting the `loadT` function executed and this is the fnction listening to the `tr` click. Why the `reactivate` function is not running? It is supposed to get executed once I have clicked on the checkbox.

I know that I'm missing something extremely small here, but I really can't spot my mistake at this momment.

**P.S** Here are the 2 functions:

```
loadT = function() {
      console.log('test1');
};

reactivate = function(){
    console.log('inside');
};
```

When I click on the checkbox it prints just: 'test1', I can't understand why the listener is not working. I have used it hundreds of times in previous projects, without any issues. My guess is that something is messed up in teh view model, but again, there are 2 seperate functions and 2 seperate listeners.

Comment: What are `reactivate/loadT` functions?

Comment: @A.Wolff just 2 seperate functions. Let's say that every function is just printing something in the console.

Comment: Change event does not work with checkboxes. You want to try `click` instead

Comment: @GôTô I tried it. The behavior is exatly teh same.

Comment: But maybe LoadT overwrites reactivate behaviour. Now, try using just any console log for both methods, do you have still same issue? And BTW, you should have posted any link which replicates your issue, not just let us guessing what could be your problem

Comment: @GôTô Really, that's quite new for me then?! Usually for checkbox, onchange should be used, not click

Comment: you should stop the event to bubbleup.

Comment: @A.Wolff My bad, it does work, I got confused with something else

Comment: @A.Wolff check my edit. The behavior is teh same, it is getting inide of the 1st function.

Comment: @Slim there must be a problem with your viewmodel, your example does [work](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/n55gv/1/). Can you share your viewmodel?

Comment: @GôTô the above fiddle is not working. In firefox when you click in the checkbox it says `click` and in chrome, when you click in teh checkbox it says `checkbox` but when you close the alert another one is popping saying `click`

Comment: @Slim Interesting, looks like a bug on FF or at least not expected behaviour

Comment: @Slim yes, but the event on the checkbox *is* fired. To prevent the event to bubbleup you'll need some code, but the event should fire. See [**doc**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-4-preventing-the-event-from-bubbling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example works with the `click` event if you add `clickBubble: false` to your markup to prevent the event from bubbling:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reactivate" 
       data-bind="event:{click: reactivate}, clickBubble: false" />
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/n55gv/3/)

Note that you will need to `return true;` to allow the default action (the box actually getting checked).

```
reactivate: function () {
        console.log('checkbox');
        return true;
    }
```

See [**doc**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-4-preventing-the-event-from-bubbling)

Note: I am not sure why, but I can't make it work with the `change` event (if someone can explain in the comments) [**Non** working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/n55gv/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Since its a checkbox I guess you need to react on if its checked or unchecked?
The KO way of doing that would be

```
ViewModel = function() {
   this.checked = ko.observable(false);
   this.checked.subscribe(this.onChecked, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype =  {
   onChecked: function(value) {
      console.log(value);
   }
};

<input data-bind="checked: checked" type="checkbox" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EG5HU/

If you do not want to act on checkstate but rather just format something you can use a computed

http://jsfiddle.net/EG5HU/1/